# css transitions blocking scrolling of window

Tags: css, css-transitions

In firefox, I get a delay and it makes scrolling the window (with trackpad on mac) virtually impossible to do it smoothly.

http://wishd.me/

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, if anything, or is this just an unintended side-effect of doing a transition on a hover.

```
.list > li > div {
  border: 1px solid #09c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #39c;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* Old browsers */

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 66%, #fbfbfb 80%, #fafafa 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */

  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(66%, #fcfcfc), color-stop(80%, #fbfbfb), color-stop(100%, #fafafa));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 66%, #fbfbfb 80%, #fafafa 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */

  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 66%, #fbfbfb 80%, #fafafa 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */

  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 66%, #fbfbfb 80%, #fafafa 100%);
  /* IE10+ */

  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #fcfcfc 66%, #fbfbfb 80%, #fafafa 100%);
  /* W3C */

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#fafafa', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */

  /*box-shadow: 1px 5px 15px #f0f0f0; */

  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #fff inset, 1px 5px 15px #f0f0f0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0 10px 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.list > li:hover > div {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #fff inset, 0px 5px 20px #ddd;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 21px;
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing a slight but noticeable delay on my PC as well.

Comment: If you put your cursor in the sidebar and scroll it is smooth, but if you put it in the middle of the page over the users list, it is jagged.

Comment: Ah, that's what you're referring to. Yes, that's where it gets **really bad**. It's probably because you're transitioning everything...

Comment: I removed the transition rules on :hover, but it still is a bit delayed.

Comment: Tried adding `transition-delay` or not?

Checking your css file, I found a lot of strange `transition` styling spread in various elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't do a through test on your issue but...

Transition styling needs not copy to the `:hover` section. Only the original section is enough. It could be the culprit.

Since the rendering speed is probably the major source of problem, you may also try adding a `transition-delay`, so that scrolling won't activate all the hoverable elements beneath.

Comment: remove :hover transitions and adding transition-delay fixed it, thanks.